# VirtualBox doesn't configure DNS for virtual machines in NAT Network mode

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, dns

I have VirtualBox 5.1.6_Ubuntu r110634 installed on my Ubuntu 16.10 host machine. I set up two virtual machines: MSEdge Windows 10 and Kali linux 2016.2. I set both VMs to NAT Network mode in the Networks configuration tab which should share my internet connection on my host machine to the virtual machines. I created a new NAT Network in VirtulBox Preferences window.

Both VMs are assigned an IP address but no DNS is configured and thus name resolution not working (see: ping, nslookup or even browsing).

I tried manually setting the DNS server in the Virtual machines to my host machine's IP address but that didn't help either.

The selected Adapter Type is Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM).

This is the `ifconfig` output from my host machine:

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.2.110  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
    inet6 fe80::5e65:a503:8004:7fd0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 50:e5:49:c2:a2:20  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 49715  bytes 54145702 (54.1 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 38321  bytes 5948667 (5.9 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 73092  bytes 4440731 (4.4 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 73092  bytes 4440731 (4.4 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I would expect some VirtualBox related interfaces here as well.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you make a screenshot of your NatNetwork you have setup? Coudl you add the output of `ifconfig` on Kali and `ipconfig` on your Windows VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to make it work. Not sure what was the magic step but here's what I did:

- uninstall virtualbox: `apt-get autoremove 'virtualbox*'`
- `apt-get clean`
- Install VirtualBox as it is described here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads. Earlier I installed VirtualBox using Ubuntu Software Center.
- Made sure my user is in the `vboxusers` group
- Started VirtualBox as root from command line, create guest devices
- Set up NAT Network, assign device to NAT Network
- voila!